# Valid JSON (for real) is throwing error in JSON.Parse

Tags: javascript, python, json, ionic-framework, udp

I am at a dead end.  I am baffled.  I am passing a stringified dictionary from Python (using json.dumps()) through UDP to an Ionic 2 (Typescript) application.

The python code generating the messages:

```
message = { 'time' :  str(round(float(op('indexFraction')[0]),3))  }
messageJSON = json.dumps(message)
#messageJSON = json.JSONEncoder().encode(message)
print(messageJSON)
op('udpout').send(messageJSON)  #sending out of TouchDesigner
```

My callback function on the Ionic side looks like this:

```
socket.on('message', function (message, remoteAddress) {
    if (message.length > 0) {
        console.log(message, typeof(message));
        // alert(message);
        // process response message

        var data = JSON.parse(message);
        console.log(data);
        if (data.time) {
            alert(data.time);
        }
    }
});
```

A sample message looks like this (typeof string):
{"time": "0.934"}

// this is a string, as evidenced by the Console.log

JSON.parse() throws the following:
index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 17

I've tried all kinds of variants on the object.  It passes as valid on JSONlint.  It's so simple, no wacky characters.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: What is at position 17? Is your sample message the one that is actually throwing the error?

Comment: Yes... the sample message is the one throwing the error.  Position 17 appears to be the final curly brace, or perhaps the space after assuming a 0 index?

Comment: Are you able to replicate this in a fiddle?

Comment: I also think position 17 is actually after the last curly brace, and the error is likely due to an invalid character.

Comment: How is there an invalid character at the end of the string, could it be coming from the Python json library?  I tried trimming the string (using .trim()) once it comes in through the UDP channel, no luck.  However, I will answer below as I have solved the issue for now...

Comment: On second thought, I'll post my workaround here -- would be great to get an answer as to where this invalid character might be coming from.  But Matt -- I think you're correct.  I have taken a substring of the message and excluded the last character, and the object deserializes properly.  Fixed by adding the line:

message = message.substring(0, message.length - 1);

Comment: Could there be some issue with the EOL? Ie that your python app is using unix and your ionic windows? I can't really see that it should matter though, just a long shot.

Comment: Not sure -- the Python is running in the TouchDesigner environment in Windows, and the Ionic is running in a Chromeview web browser on Android (AFAIK).  There definitely seems to be an extraneous character (perhaps a CR?), and extracting the substring seems to do the trick.